# How to use a oracle trigger to insert(update, delete) to mysql in the remote server

Tags: mysql, oracle, server, triggers

I have an issue on this.
Is it possible to make oracle trigger to insert(update, delete) to mysql in the remote server?
If possible, how to do it?
Please help me.

Comment: 1) Read [ask], 2) post [mcve], 3) post error, and read [Why is Help Me not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question
)

Comment: certainly it is possible.  You will need to set up a connection using the Oracle Transparent Gateway (OTG), and define a database link.  Documentation for the link is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-DATABASE-LINK.html#GUID-D966642A-B19E-449D-9968-1121AF06D793).  An overview of the OTG is [here](https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2018/09/19/the-oracle-transparent-gateway/)